# how to vectorize a for loop on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i am working whit a data of about 200,000 rows, in one column of the pandas i have some values that have a empty list, the most of them are list whit several values, here is a picture:

[image]

what i want to do is change the empty sets whit this set

```
[[close*0.95,close*0.94]]
```

where the close is the close value on the table,  the for loop that i use is this one:

```
for i in range(1,len(data3.index)):
    close = data3.close[data3.index==data3.index[i]].values[0]
    sell_list = data3.sell[data3.index==data3.index[i]].values[0]
    buy_list = data3.buy[data3.index==data3.index[i]].values[0]
    if len(sell_list)== 0:
        data3.loc[data3.index[i],"sell"].append([[close*1.05,close*1.06]])
    if len(buy_list)== 0:
        data3.loc[data3.index[i],"buy"].append([[close*0.95,close*0.94]])
```

i tried to make it work whit multithread but as i need to read all the table to do the next step i cant split the data, i hope you can help me to make a kind of lamda function to apply the df, or something, i am not to much skilled on this, thanks for reading!

the expected output of the row and column "buy" of and empty set should be  [[[11554, 11566]]]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). What is the expected output? You want a list of lists like `[[close*0.95, close*0.94]]` or you really intend to get a triple nested list `[[[close*0.95, close*0.94]]]` like you have in the other rows?

Comment: the structure should be like this [[[11531, 11543], [11543, 11554], [11554, 11566], [11566, 11578]]])] but in the case of having an empty set i would like to have the nested list [[[11554, 11566]]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'close': [11763, 21763, 31763], 'buy':[[], [[21763, 21767]], []]})
```

```
   close                 buy
0  11763                  []
1  21763  [[[21763, 21767]]]
2  31763                  []
```

You could do it like this:

```
# Create mask (a bit faster than df['buy'].apply(len) == 0).
# Assumes there are no NaNs in the column. If you have NaNs, use pd.apply.
m = [len(l) == 0 for l in df['buy'].tolist()]

# Create triple nested lists and assign.
df.loc[m, 'buy'] = list(df.loc[m, ['close', 'close']].mul([0.95, 0.94]).to_numpy()[:, None][:, None])

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   close                                 buy
0  11763            [[[11174.85, 11057.22]]]
1  21763                  [[[21763, 21767]]]
2  31763  [[[30174.85, 29857.219999999998]]]
```

### Some explanation:

- `m` is a boolean mask that selects the rows of the DataFrame with an empty list in the `'buy'` column:

```
m = [len(l) == 0 for l in df['buy'].tolist()]

# Or (a bit slower)

# "Apply the len() function to all lists in the column.
m = df['buy'].apply(len) == 0

print(m)
```

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: buy, dtype: bool
```

We can use this mask to select where to calculate the values.

- `df.loc[m, ['close', 'close']].mul([0.95, 0.94])` duplicates the `'close'` column and calculates the vectorised product of all the `(close, close)` pairs with `(0.95, 0.94)` to obtain `(close*0.94, close*0.94)` in each row of the resulting array.
- `[:, None][:, None]` is just a trick to create two additional axes on the resulting array. This is required since you want triple nested lists (`[[[]]]`).

Comment: hahaha just love it, need to do a lot of stuff like this, i really dont fully understand this way of thinking  but thanks a lot you give me a lot to think!

Comment: @mimus I edited the answer and added a bit of additional information if you are interested!